# ssh-agent error on ubuntu server 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, zsh, environment-variables

I have an Ubuntu Server 10.04 installation on Linode. I am trying to use ssh-agent to stop typing my passphrase everytime I need to push some changes to GitHub. I am using the script provided by GitHub [here](http://help.github.com/working-with-key-passphrases/). But when I source my `.zshrc` file or when I logout and log back in I get the following error message:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Does anyone know what the the problem might be and how I could fix it please?

Comment: There's something wrong in your `.zshrc`. Line 47, I think (unless my crystal ball's gone misaligned again). Post your `.zshrc`, and try adding `set -x` at the beginning to see a trace of what it's doing.

Comment: here is my `.zshrc`: http://pastie.org/1621083

Answer (score 1):

Your .zshrc may be modifying the DISPLAY variable, or modifying access to the screen.  Normally ssh-agent is started when you start gnome.  The variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set to the socket of your ssh-agent.  If this variable is set, then ssh-agent will try to open window to get the password for your key when it is needed.

If your display is not accessible you can use ssh-add to add the key from the command line. Do this after you reboot.  You also need to repeat this if your key ages out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves one part of the problem, which is that the second error message (`Error: Can't open display: (null)`) is unrelated to ssh-agent. It's related to oh-my-zsh. On the other hand, still don't know why ssh-agent fails (and why I get the first error message), but it might also be because of oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ssh-agent is not running when you source the file. You have lines 46 and 47 commented out:

```
# eval `ssh-agent`
# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Try uncommenting those lines.